# PostGIS Out-DB Rasters - Segmentation Fault

Tags: postgis, gdal, postgresql, netcdf

I am loading data from a NETCDF file with raster2pgsql, which I would like to keep as an out-DB raster. The command I use is (note the -R option):

```
raster2pgsql -s 96482 -I -d -F -R NETCDF:"/home/rowangaffney/Projects/CPER_DB_Testing/GIS_Data/MODIS_8day_VI.nc":_250m_16_days_NDVImodtest_rr modtest_rr | psql -d cper_test2
```

This seems to load ok:

```
cper_test2=# \d+ modtest_rr
                                                  Table "public.modtest_rr"
  Column  |  Type   | Collation | Nullable |                 Default                 | Storage  | Stats target | Description
----------+---------+-----------+----------+-----------------------------------------+----------+--------------+-------------
 rid      | integer |           | not null | nextval('modtest_rr_rid_seq'::regclass) | plain    |              |
 rast     | raster  |           |          |                                         | extended |              |
 filename | text    |           |          |                                         | extended |              |
Indexes:
    "modtest_rr_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (rid)
    "modtest_rr_st_convexhull_idx" gist (st_convexhull(rast))

cper_test2=# SELECT (ST_METADATA(rast)).* FROM modtest_rr;
    upperleftx     |    upperlefty    | width | height |      scalex      |      scaley       | skewx | skewy | srid  | numbands
-------------------+------------------+-------+--------+------------------+-------------------+-------+-------+-------+----------
 -8820663.32543447 | 4544750.26460167 |    83 |     44 | 231.656358264387 | -231.656358263455 |     0 |     0 | 96842 |      834
(1 row)
```

And GDAL can read it ok:

```
gdalinfo PG:"host=localhost dbname=cper_test2 port=5434 table=modtest_rr"
Driver: PostGISRaster/PostGIS Raster driver
Files: none associated
Size is 83, 44
Coordinate System is:
PROJCS["Sinusoidal",
    GEOGCS["GCS_Undefined",
        DATUM["Undefined",
            SPHEROID["User_Defined_Spheroid",6371007.181,0.0]],
        PRIMEM["Greenwich",0.0],
        UNIT["Degree",0.0174532925199433]],
    PROJECTION["Sinusoidal"],
    PARAMETER["False_Easting",0.0],
    PARAMETER["False_Northing",0.0],
    PARAMETER["Central_Meridian",0.0],
    UNIT["Meter",1.0]]
Origin = (-8820663.325434470549226,4544750.264601670205593)
Pixel Size = (231.656358264386995,-231.656358263454990)
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  (-8820663.325, 4544750.265) (104d54'15.75"W, 40d52'18.75"N)
Lower Left  (-8820663.325, 4534557.385) (104d45'34.09"W, 40d46'48.75"N)
Upper Right (-8801435.848, 4544750.265) (104d40'32.53"W, 40d52'18.75"N)
Lower Right (-8801435.848, 4534557.385) (104d31'52.01"W, 40d46'48.75"N)
Center      (-8811049.587, 4539653.825) (104d43' 3.29"W, 40d49'33.75"N)
Band 1 Block=83x44 Type=Float32, ColorInterp=Undefined
  NoData Value=-3000
Band 2 Block=83x44 Type=Float32, ColorInterp=Undefined
  NoData Value=-3000
Band 3 Block=83x44 Type=Float32, ColorInterp=Undefined
  NoData Value=-3000
Band 4 Block=83x44 Type=Float32, ColorInterp=Undefined
  NoData Value=-3000
Band 5 Block=83x44 Type=Float32, ColorInterp=Undefined
  NoData Value=-3000
...
```

However, when I try to query the data I get:

```
cper_test2=# SELECT ST_SUMMARYSTATS(rast) FROM modtest_RR;
SSL SYSCALL error: EOF detected
The connection to the server was lost. Attempting reset: Failed.
!> ^C
!> \q
```

I am not sure where all the logs are, but I found /var/log/postgresql/postgresql-10-main.log, which has:

```
2019-07-19 09:17:38 MDT [1425-55] LOG:  server process (PID 14277) was terminated by signal 11: Segmentation fault
2019-07-19 09:17:38 MDT [1425-56] DETAIL:  Failed process was running: SELECT ST_SUMMARYSTATS(rast) FROM modtest_rr;
2019-07-19 09:17:38 MDT [1425-57] LOG:  terminating any other active server processes
2019-07-19 09:17:38 MDT [14269-1] WARNING:  terminating connection because of crash of another server process
2019-07-19 09:17:38 MDT [14269-2] DETAIL:  The postmaster has commanded this server process to roll back the current transaction and exit, because another server process exited abnormally and possibly corrupted shared memory.
2019-07-19 09:17:38 MDT [14269-3] HINT:  In a moment you should be able to reconnect to the database and repeat your command.
2019-07-19 09:17:38 MDT [14973-1] rowangaffney@cper_test2 FATAL:  the database system is in recovery mode
2019-07-19 09:17:38 MDT [14974-1] rowangaffney@cper_test2 FATAL:  the database system is in recovery mode
2019-07-19 09:17:38 MDT [1425-58] LOG:  all server processes terminated; reinitializing
2019-07-19 09:17:38 MDT [14975-1] LOG:  database system was interrupted; last known up at 2019-07-19 09:04:22 MDT
2019-07-19 09:17:39 MDT [14975-2] LOG:  database system was not properly shut down; automatic recovery in progress
2019-07-19 09:17:39 MDT [14975-3] LOG:  redo starts at 9/4CE01B00
2019-07-19 09:17:39 MDT [14975-4] LOG:  invalid record length at 9/4CE01B38: wanted 24, got 0
2019-07-19 09:17:39 MDT [14975-5] LOG:  redo done at 9/4CE01B00
2019-07-19 09:17:39 MDT [1425-59] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
```

Any idea why it is getting a segmentation fault? Where could I find more logs that may have more details about the seg-fault?

If I load the raster data directly into the database, everything works fine!

Here are the details on my software:

```
            postgis_version            |                                                                   version                                                                   
---------------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 2.5 USE_GEOS=1 USE_PROJ=1 USE_STATS=1 | PostgreSQL 10.8 (Ubuntu 10.8-1.pgdg16.04+1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.11) 5.4.0 20160609, 64-bit

raster2pgsql -?
RELEASE: 2.4.3 GDAL_VERSION=22 (r16312)
```

## **UPDATE:**

When trying to load the data from a more recent version of raster2pgsql, the attempt fails:

```
raster2pgsql -?
RELEASE: 2.5.2 GDAL_VERSION=111 (r17328)
```

Before I was using a raster2pgsql that was inside a container (see above) and loading to the host database... Any ideas why raster2pgsql (based on gdal 2.5.2) on the host side is erroring? I think this is likely related to why database can't read external raster.

Comment: try https://postgis.net/docs/RT_ST_SummaryStatsAgg.html instead?

Comment: ST_SummaryStatsAgg(rast, 1, TRUE, 1) produces the same result. Furthermore, these functions work with the in-database raster.

Comment: I googled the error message and got https://serverfault.com/questions/706047/terminating-connection-because-of-crash-of-another-server-process  Have you watched your ram to see what is consumed during this process?